# Getting the path of the home directory in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Okay, I've checked `Environment.SpecialFolder`, but there's nothing in there for this.

I want to get the home directory of the current user in C#. (e.g. `c:\documents and settings\user` under XP, `c:\users\user` under Vista, and `/home/user` under Unix.)

I know I can read enviroment variables to find this out, but I want to do this in a cross-platform way.

Is there any way I can do this with .NET (preferably using mscorlib)?

**UPDATE**: Okay, this is the code I ended up using:

```
string homePath = (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix || 
                   Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.MacOSX)
    ? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")
    : Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%");
```

Comment: Dunno about your machine, but on my XP box %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% is a network directory, not c:\Documents and Settings\user\MSalters\

Comment: To be honest, I consider this exact problem to be an underimplementation of .NET... you should look at the documentation for CSIDLS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx) to see a full list of what Windows supports: What you are actually looking for is CSIDL_PROFILE, which is supported in Windows, but not by .NET for some unfathomable reason.

Comment: I think you should put the result in an answer, next time.

Comment: PlatformID.MacOSX is not necessary, PlatformID.Unix returns true on MacOSX, too (or at the very least it used to).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` doesn't actually return the home folder, it returns the *My Documents* folder. The safest way to get the home folder on Win32 is to read `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`. Reading environment variables is actually very portable to do (across Unix and Windows), so I'm not sure why the poster wanted to *not* do it.

*Edited to add:* For crossplatform (Windows/Unix) C#, I'd read `$HOME` on Unix and OSX and `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` on Windows.

Comment: I know for a fact HOMEDRIVE doesn't exist on *nix, and normally it's just HOME, not HOMEPATH.

Comment: Matthew, you're right. I added a clarification on the original comment.

Comment: Can you not use %USERPROFILE% on Windows?

Comment: Mac OSX *is* UNIX, officially. It also works on Linux, which is similar enough to UNIX.

Comment: $HOME works on OS X too. This still isn't the correct answer as far as I'm concerned though since you're doing platform detection... but to get at the exact values asked for, that's about what you have to do.

Comment: Actually, OS X is BSD, but that's a distinction for the anals of some history book or another...

Comment: Thank you, I posted the code I ended up using to the original question.

Comment: person-b, %USERPROFILE% and %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% are often the same on personal PCs, but often point to different places in networked environments. E.g., at work my USERPROFILE is C:\Documents and Settings\username but home directory is Z:\, which is a networked drive which is backed up by IT regularly.

Comment: I have exactly the same setup at my work environment as sigint.

Answer (score 160):

You are looking for `Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile` which refers to `C:\Users\myname` on Windows and `/home/myname` on Unix/Linux:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
```

Note that `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` is My Documents (or Documents in win7 and above), but same as home directory on Unix/Linux.

Comment: Note that UserProfile is new in .NET 4.0, if you use .NET 2.0/3.5, you have to call win32 API manually with value 40 for UserProfile

Comment: And "My Documents" isn't the same as the home directory, except in Windows 95, 98 and ME.

Comment: Don't forget to use System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar to build your file path in order to keep it portable.

Comment: Don't use DirectorySeperatorChar manually.  Use Path.Combine.

Comment: This works with .net core on Linux too, returning the home folder

Answer (score 17):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
```

For reference, it is infact contained in `mscorlib`.

Comment: That returns the My Documents folder.

Comment: "My Documents" *is* the closest thing Windows has to a home directory.

Comment: @MStallers No, %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% is.

Comment: Not quite... but the alternative is PInvoke, and the OP asked for a managed solution.

Comment: Note that Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile is available in .NET 4.0, which is what you want

Comment: return System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(
                System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "..")
            );

Comment: Your suggestion, Stefan, isn't actually a good one. One shouldn't assume the parent of the user's My Documents directory is automatically the user home directory. The user can set any folder as their My Documents folder.

Answer (score 8):

In DotNetCore 1.1 `System.Environment.SpecialFolder` does not exist. It might exist in 2.0-beta. Until then, to do this you can use the following:

```
var envHome = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ? "HOMEPATH" : "HOME";
var home = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(envHome);`
```

Comment: I'm using 2.0 and `System.Environment.SpecialFolder` exists

Answer (score 4):

The bottom line answer is No.  The is no simple System based method in .NET to get the Home directory such that we could expect an implementation in both .NET on Windows and in Mono.

You will need to do some OS detection and branch to OS specific code.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `GetEnvironmentVariable` in `System.IO`:

```
public string GetUserHome() {
    var homeDrive = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEDRIVE");
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(homeDrive))
    {
        var homePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEPATH");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(homePath))
        {            
            var fullHomePath = homeDrive + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + homePath;
            return Path.Combine(fullHomePath, "myFolder");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Environment variable error, there is no 'HOMEPATH'");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Environment variable error, there is no 'HOMEDRIVE'");
    }
}
```

Then it produces under windows: `C:\\\\Users\\myusername\\myFolder`

Note that if you use

```
var fullHomePath = Path.Combine(homeDrive.ToString(), homePath.ToString())
```

it fails because it produces: `\\Users\\myusername\\myFolder`

Answer (score 1):

When you say cross-platform way, what other OSs do you need to support? You may need to do some simple OS detection to select the method for finding the home directory if you're running on a non-Windows OS.

[This website](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32384) seems to give a way to do what you need in Windows.

Comment: Unless you're using some braindead implementation of the Framework Environment.GetFolder() should work cross-platform.

Comment: *Should*. MS's implementation doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference, the list of pre-defined variables in Windows 10, taken from [Windows 10 default environment variables](https://richardbuz.de/faq/microsoft/windows-10-default-environment-variables).

| VARIABLE | WINDOWS 10 |
| --- | --- |
| %ALLUSERSPROFILE% | C:\ProgramData |
| %APPDATA% | C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming |
| %CD% | Current directory full path. (cmd only) |
| %CMDCMDLINE% | Returns exact command line used to start current cmd.exe session. (cmd only) |
| %CMDEXTVERSION% | Number of current command processor extensions. (cmd only) |
| %CommonProgramFiles% | C:\Program Files\Common Files |
| %CommonProgramFiles(x86)% | C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files |
| %CommonProgramW6432% | C:\Program Files\Common Files |
| %COMPUTERNAME% | The computer name of the current local system. |
| %COMSPEC% | C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe |
| %DATE% | Current date in format determined by Date command. (cmd only) |
| %ERRORLEVEL% | Number defining exit status of previous command or program. (cmd only) |
| %HOMEDRIVE% | C:| |
| %HOMEPATH% | C:\Users{username} |
| %LOCALAPPDATA% | C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local |
| %LOGONSERVER% | \{domain_logon_server} \MicrosoftAccount |
| %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% | 8 |
| %OS% | Windows_NT |
| %PATH% | C:\Windows; C:\Windows\System32; C:\Windows\System32\Wbem; C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 |
| %PathExt% | .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC |
| %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% | AMD64 |
| %PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER% | Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel |
| %PROCESSOR_LEVEL% | 6 |
| %PROCESSOR_REVISION% | 9e09 |
| %PROGRAMDATA% | C:\ProgramData |
| %PROGRAMFILES% | C:\Program Files |
| %ProgramW6432% | C:\Program Files |
| %PROGRAMFILES(X86)% | C:\Program Files (x86) |
| %PROMPT% | Code for current command prompt format. Code is usually $P$G (cmd only) |
| %PSModulePath% | C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules| |
| %PUBLIC% | C:\Users\Public |
| %RANDOM% | To get random number between 0 and 32767. (cmd only) |
| %SessionName% | When logging on directly to machine, returns "Console". When client connects via terminal server session, is combination of connection name, followed by pound symbol {#} and session number. |
| %SystemDrive% | C: |
| %SystemRoot% | C:\Windows |
| %TEMP% | C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Temp |
| %TMP% | C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Temp |
| %TIME% | Current time in format determined by Time command. (cmd only) |
| %USERDOMAIN% | The network domain name associated with the current user. |
| %USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE% | The network domain name associated with the current roaming profile. |
| %USERNAME% | {username} |
| %USERPROFILE% | C:\Users{username} |
| %WINDIR% | C:\Windows |

Comment: Had to manually put it to markdown, so if I made an error, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a machine to test it on, but `%HOMESHARE%` might work for you.  Otherwise, here's a pretty good [list of environment variables](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true).