# How to set gtk file chooser button default to user's home folder

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, default, filechooser

I've got a gtk file chooser button on my application I am writing in c# using Mono Develop. I would like to set the file chooser's default location to the users' home directory regardless of what user is running it.

I've tried the ~/ short cut - fchFolder1.SetCurrentFolder("~/"); - but this did not work. I was just wondering if there was a value that the gtk file chooser used to refer to the users home directory? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unix, you can either get the HOME environment variable or use `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`.

In Windows, expand `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` to get the "home" directory, or use the same `GetFolderPath` call to get the "My Documents" directory.

Discussion about the HOME and HOMEDRIVE+HOMEPATH approach: [Getting the path of the home directory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143706/getting-the-path-of-the-home-directory-in-c)

Comment: Thanks I used the code on the link to the discussion you posted :) just in case any one else has the same problem I used the following code to make it cross platform:

string homePath = (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix || Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.MacOSX)
    ? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")
    : Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%");

Answer (score 1):

In C, one would use `g_get_home_dir()` to find the user's home directory, and set the file chooser's current location to that, but as far as I can tell, that function isn't wrapped in GTK#. Someone asked the same question on the [GTK# mailing list](http://lists.ximian.com/archives/public/gtk-sharp-list/2004-July/004510.html) and the answer was to use

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath (SpecialFolder.Personal)
```