# How do I tell user "home" folder in .net?

Tags: .net, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the path of the home directory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143706/getting-the-path-of-the-home-directory-in-c)

I know the method to discover folder like `C:\Users\MyLogin\Desktop` (Vista) or `C:\Documents And Settings\MyLogin\Desktop` (XP). But how do I get the path to `C:\Users\MyLogin`, that is "user home", in .net? I am looking for a generic and safe API call, not "Desktop up one level".

Comment: Konrad did you see this link?


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143706/getting-the-path-of-the-home-directory-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this:

```
string userFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```