# C# Question for downloading and running files

Tags: c#

Recently, I've been trying to program a C# application in visual studio. I want it to be able to download a folder onto the person's desktop. Farther, I was hoping to be able to run a exe file in the folder I downloaded twice, as soon as it was done downloading. I am new to C#, and need some help. While looking through some forums online, I found you could use the command marked with (1) at the bottom.

The problem is I have no idea what I would use to make it download a file to the same location on everyone's pc. Because everyone's name might be different. IE: user12345(2) and user54321(3)

```
(1): using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.DownloadFile("A link", @"c:\some\local\filename");
                
            }

(2): using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.DownloadFile("", @"C:\Users\**user12345**\Desktop");
                
            }

(3): using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.DownloadFile("", @"C:\Users\**user54321**\Desktop");
                
            }
```

Thanks for the help,
Atomic

Comment: What if that drive doesn't exist either?

Comment: This question might help : [Getting the path of the home directory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143706)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a path to the desktop for current user in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/634142/10263)